# How to be able to look at more than one window of data in Rstudio when apply View()?

Tags: r, view, rstudio

Every time I apply View() on any data, it replaces the actual window of data from previous View(). I assume it should be some configuration on Rstudio, but I don't know how and on the internet it's not a common problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the title of the `View()` window with the `title` option, e.g.:

> View(mtcars, title = "new_window")

Of if you use a pipe:

> mtcars %>%
> View(., title = "new_window")

Just make sure that your windows have different titles.

Comment: Just to add. This happened because I piped the View() so it has no name and takes "." by default, replacing every time it is applied.